# I thought I defined my jQuery function, but I keep getting an "is not defined" error. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

My HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" />
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="someForm">
            <input type="button" value="Click me" onClick="myFunction()" />
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My script.js file:

```
function myFunction(){
    $("#result").html("BUTTON WORKS");
}
```

I have Firebug, and whenever I click the button, Firebug throws me this error:

> ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're attaching events in-line. That's what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Shmiddty: How would that cause the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by combining answers from @Susbanth, @MBO, and @dystroy.

Here's my new HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="someForm">
            <input type="button" value="Click me" />
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I added "http" to the jQuery source, closed the tag, and removed the 'onClick' from inside the HTML.

Here's the updated script.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=button]").on("click",function(){
        $("div#result").html("BUTTON WORK");
    });
});
```

I made the onClick event a jQuery event.

Answer (score 2):

`script` can't be a self closing tag in HTML (it works on some browsers, depending on the doctype, but it's not correct). You must add a closing tag.

Replace

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" />
```

with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The script element pointing to your script probably isn't parsed correctly due to this error.

From [the norm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/spec.html#script) :

> A script element must have both a start tag and an end tag.
>
> Blockquote

Comment: Actually in HTML there are no self-closing tags. Even <br/> is parsed as <br> with garbage at end of tag. But only matters in tags like script, iframe...

Answer (score 1):

Might be due to file reference issue.

It is a better practice to attach the event in the js file instead of HTML.

```
<form name="someForm">
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me" />
</form>


$('#btn').on('click', function(){
    $("#result").html("BUTTON WORKS");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you open that file locally (you have `file://` in address bar) or from some server (`http://` protocol in address bar)? Because if you open file locally, you actually try to load jquery from address:

> file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

which is incorrect. It happens, because you use `//ajax.googleapis.com/...` as adress, which refers the same protocol as currently opened page.

Either change it to:

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js

of upload your file to some server (or even install one locally) and test it through full http request.